# Ionic Project, Not working on phone but working during development

Tags: javascript, php, android, ionic-framework

Got something that i can't understand.

I am learning an ionic framework and created a simple login page, i am able to process through the editor (i am using Atom Editor with ionic live preview installed) as well through browser which i can sign in or register and it will bring me to next page.

But it really weird that, i cant login or register when i compiled the project to .APK and installed on my phone.

Any ideas guys?

**UPDATE**

Cant run it in android emulator as well, but working fine in browser using ionic serve.

Here is some of my code.

**login.html**

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-balanced">
  <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-view>
    <ion-content class="padding has-header">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <input type="text" ng-model="login.username" placeholder="Username">
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <input type="password" ng-model="login.password" placeholder="Password">
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
      <button nav-clear class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="LogIn()">Login</button>
      <button class="button button-positive button-clear button-full" ui-sref="signup">Register now!</button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
    require_once 'dbConfig.php';
    // check username or password from database
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $user = $request->username;
    $password = $request->password;

    $results = mysql_query("SELECT email, password FROM tbl_user WHERE email='".$user."' AND password='".$password."' LIMIT 1") or die('{"error":"Login error! Code: 003"}');
    $match  = mysql_num_rows($results);
    if($match > 0 ){
      echo "1";
    }else{
      echo "0";
    }
?>
```

**controller.js**

```
    angular.module('ionicApp.controllers', [])


.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
})


.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http, $ionicPopup) {
  $scope.showAlert = function(msg) {
      $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: msg.title,
          template: msg.message,
          okText: 'Ok',
          okType: 'button-positive'
      });
    };


  $scope.login = {};
  $scope.LogIn = function() {
    if(!$scope.login.username){
      $scope.showAlert({
        title: "Information",
        message: "Please enter your email address"
      });
    }else if(!$scope.login.password){
      $scope.showAlert({
        title: "Information",
        message: "Please enter your password"
      });
    }else{
      var request = $http({
          method: "post",
          url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/api/login.php",
          data: {
            username: $scope.login.username,
            password: $scope.login.password
          },
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        });

        /*Successful HTTP post request or not */

        request.success(function (data){
          if (data == '1'){
            $state.go('app.test');
            }
          else {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                  title: 'Login failed!',
                  template: 'Please check your credentials!'
            });
          }
        })
    }
  };
});
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic','ionicApp.controllers'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
      url: "/app",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })


    .state('app.test', {
      url: '/test',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/test.html'
        }
      }
    })


    .state('login', {
      url: "/login",
      templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    });
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that, the problem is related to cordova plugin.

Anyone that encounter this issue can try this fix.

just run **cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist** in our project folder and rebuild it.